# Routing for ajax in symfony project

Tags: ajax, symfony

First. All is working, but i your tips for the projekt.

I create many projects with Symfony2 and there everywhere i use ajax, mostly with query.

Here is my routing.yml

```
_ajax:
    path: /_ajax
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeAllgemeinBundle:Default:ajax }
```

Here the call in the js

```
function checkStatus()
{
    var url = $("#ajaxurl").data("url");

    var postData = [
        { "id":"1", "name":"bob"},
        { "id":"2", "name":"jonas"}
    ]

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            url: url,
            dataType: "json"
        }).done( function(resp) {
            console.log("mit done " + resp.text);
        }).fail( function(){
            console.log("Fehler");
        });
}
```

But here is the question:

Should i handle evey ajax with one route and set one variable and call the functions by name in the controller like

```
{"job":"saveAdress"}
```

or should I  create different route's for every job like

```
_ajax_saveAdress:
    path: /_ajax/saveAdress
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeAllgmeinBundle:Default:ajaxSaveJob }
```

Comment: Its based on the requirements what you want to achieve from ajax a validation check, send email ,db usage etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find it easier in a larger application to split out your paths into individual routes and base the routes logically on their domain objects and/or operations.

I would recommend considering a RESTful approach to your URLs so that you operations might look something like the following:

- `GET /jobs/{jobId}/address`
- `POST /jobs/{jobId}/address` (also accepting `PUT` and `DELETE` methods)

If you want to get fancy you can leverage the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) along with a serializer (e.g. [JMSSerializerBundler](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle)) to handle formatting of your requests in either HTML, JSON, or XML as necessary.